# Sci-Fi Novel Earth with space station defense against aliens and a space fleet

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space, soft-sci-fi

I remember reading this novel when I was younger and here are some of the details I remember:

Earth has a space station that is used as a main defense against aliens, however, I believe the Earth also had a space fleet. The aliens would only attack the top 20 'tribes' on the planet since Earth hadn't unified yet. Earth also has an AI that shoots down missile barrages aimed at the planet that performs better than expected. Earth also has a satellite that shoots a powerful laser that destroys alien space ships.

Also, humans use the wrecks of alien space ships to make missiles. There is also one scene where someone has to fly a fighter into a hanger at full speed and it gets posted on YouTube.

Comment: Can you [edit] in some more details, for example, do you know when you saw this?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The Youtube reference puts it somewhere in the last ten years or so

Comment: If the phrase, "I don't know whether to give the kid a mast or a medal" seem familiar, Revenant's answer is what you're looking for. Specifically, "Citadel", the second in the series. "Citadel" came out in 2011, so you might check to see if the date is right.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the 20 tribes thing this kinda sounds like it could be the troy rising series by John Ringo pretty much everything else is in there somewhere in some form or another

[Abandon all hope of productivity ye who enter here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TroyRising)